# Find & Extract local maximum on scatter plots

Tags: r, plot, time-series, derivative, timeserieschart

Here is a sample of my data.

```
df <- tibble(x = seq(-10, 28, by = 0.5),
             a = c(-4*10^-13, -4*10^-13, -4*10^-13, -3*10^-13, -4*10^-13, -4*10^-13, -2*10^-13, -1*10^-13, -2*10^-13, -2*10^-13, -1*10^-13, -2*10^-13, -2*10^-13, -2*10^-13, -2*10^-13, -1*10^-13, -2*10^-13, -2*10^-13, -2*10^-13, -2*10^-13, -2*10^-13, -2*10^-13, -2*10^-13, -2*10^-13, -2*10^-13, -2*10^-13, -2*10^-13, -2*10^-13, -2*10^-13, -3*10^-13, -3*10^-13, -3*10^-13, -3*10^-13, -3*10^-13, -3*10^-13, -3*10^-13, -3*10^-13, -3*10^-13, -1*10^-14, -4*10^-12,  1*10^-11,  9*10^-11, -1*10^-09, 6*10^-09, 4*10^-08, 7*10^-08, 8*10^-08, 6*10^-08, 5*10^-08, 4*10^-08, 4*10^-08, 4*10^-08, 4*10^-08, 4*10^-08, 5*10^-08, 5*10^-08, 5*10^-08, 5*10^-08, 6*10^-08, 5*10^-08, 6*10^-08, 6*10^-08, 7*10^-08, 7*10^-08, 7*10^-08, 7*10^-08, 7*10^-08, 8*10^-08, 8*10^-08, 9*10^-08, 9*10^-08, 9*10^-08, 1*10^-07, 1*10^-07, 1*10^-07, 1*10^-07, 1*10^-07),
             b = c(-4*10^-13, -4*10^-13, -3*10^-13, -3*10^-13, -2*10^-13, -3*10^-13, -2*10^-13, -2*10^-13, -2*10^-13, -2*10^-13, -2*10^-13, -2*10^-13, -2*10^-13, -2*10^-13, -1*10^-13, -2*10^-13, -2*10^-13, -7*10^-14, -2*10^-13, -2*10^-13, -2*10^-13, -2*10^-13, -2*10^-13, -2*10^-13, -2*10^-13, -2*10^-13, -2*10^-13, -3*10^-13, -3*10^-13, -2*10^-13, -3*10^-13, -3*10^-13, -3*10^-13, -3*10^-13, -3*10^-13, -3*10^-13, -4*10^-13, -3*10^-14, -2*10^-12,  6*10^-12, -3*10^-11,  1*10^-10, -6*10^-10, 5*10^-09, 2*10^-08, 3*10^-08, 6*10^-08, 6*10^-08, 4*10^-08, 4*10^-08, 3*10^-08, 3*10^-08, 4*10^-08, 4*10^-08, 4*10^-08, 4*10^-08, 4*10^-08, 5*10^-08, 5*10^-08, 5*10^-08, 6*10^-08, 6*10^-08, 6*10^-08, 7*10^-08, 7*10^-08, 7*10^-08, 8*10^-08, 8*10^-08, 8*10^-08, 9*10^-08, 9*10^-08, 9*10^-08, 1*10^-07, 1*10^-07, 1*10^-07, 1*10^-07, 1*10^-07),
             c = c(-3*10^-13, -4*10^-13, -3*10^-13, -2*10^-13, -2*10^-13, -2*10^-13, -2*10^-13, -1*10^-13, -2*10^-13, -2*10^-13, -2*10^-13, -2*10^-13, -1*10^-13, -1*10^-13, -2*10^-13, -2*10^-13, -2*10^-13, -1*10^-13, -1*10^-13, -2*10^-13, -2*10^-13, -2*10^-13, -2*10^-13, -2*10^-13, -2*10^-13, -2*10^-13, -3*10^-13, -2*10^-13, -2*10^-13, -3*10^-13, -3*10^-13, -3*10^-13, -3*10^-13, -3*10^-13, -3*10^-13, -3*10^-13, -2*10^-13, -4*10^-13, -2*10^-12,  5*10^-12,  3*10^-11, -2*10^-10, -6*10^-10, 6*10^-09, 2*10^-08, 6*10^-08, 8*10^-08, 8*10^-08, 7*10^-08, 6*10^-08, 6*10^-08, 6*10^-08, 7*10^-08, 7*10^-08, 8*10^-08, 9*10^-08, 9*10^-08, 1*10^-07, 1*10^-07, 1*10^-07, 1*10^-07, 1*10^-07, 1*10^-07, 1*10^-07, 2*10^-07, 2*10^-07, 2*10^-07, 2*10^-07, 2*10^-07, 2*10^-07, 2*10^-07, 2*10^-07, 2*10^-07, 2*10^-07, 3*10^-07, 3*10^-07, 3*10^-07),
             d = c(-5*10^-13, -3*10^-13, -2*10^-13, -3*10^-13, -3*10^-13, -2*10^-13, -2*10^-13, -3*10^-13, -2*10^-13, -1*10^-13, -3*10^-13, -2*10^-13, -1*10^-13, -2*10^-13, -2*10^-13, -2*10^-13, -2*10^-13, -2*10^-13, -2*10^-13, -2*10^-13, -2*10^-13, -2*10^-13, -2*10^-13, -3*10^-13, -2*10^-13, -2*10^-13, -2*10^-13, -3*10^-13, -2*10^-13, -2*10^-13, -3*10^-13, -3*10^-13, -3*10^-13, -3*10^-13, -3*10^-13, -3*10^-13, -3*10^-13, -3*10^-13, -2*10^-13, -2*10^-12,  1*10^-11, -9*10^-12, -5*10^-10, 5*10^-09, 2*10^-08, 3*10^-08, 5*10^-08, 7*10^-08, 8*10^-08, 7*10^-08, 5*10^-08, 5*10^-08, 5*10^-08, 6*10^-08, 6*10^-08, 6*10^-08, 7*10^-08, 8*10^-08, 8*10^-08, 8*10^-08, 1*10^-07, 1*10^-07, 9*10^-08, 1*10^-07, 1*10^-07, 1*10^-07, 1*10^-07, 1*10^-07, 1*10^-07, 1*10^-07, 1*10^-07, 1*10^-07, 2*10^-07, 2*10^-07, 2*10^-07, 2*10^-07, 2*10^-07),
             z = c(x*10^-10))
head(df)
mlt <- as.data.frame.array(reshape2::melt(df, id = "x"))
names(mlt) <- sub("value", "y", names(mlt))
head(mlt)
myplot <- ggplot(mlt, aes(x = mlt$x, y = mlt$y, group = as.factor(mlt$variable), color = as.factor(mlt$variable)))
myplot + geom_line() + theme(legend.position = c(0.40,0.75))
```

[image: ggplot of df]

I would like to retrieve the row in **df** containing local maximum on each variable a, b, c, d, z. if no peak, return NULL or NA (as we can see, variable z is not showing any peak).

I have extracted the peaks that I wanted manually.
Here are their location on each variables a, b, c & d.

```
LocationOfPeak_var.a <- df[c(47), c(1,2)]
LocationOfPeak_var.b <- df[c(49), c(1,3)]
LocationOfPeak_var.c <- df[c(49), c(1,4)]
LocationOfPeak_var.d <- df[c(50), c(1,5)]
```

I would like to make this, using R, (not manually).
How to overcome this?
I know my question is a bit tricky but I really need some help.

Here is the least worst way that I've tried (found on SO) but output data does not satisfy me either (since I really don't see any maximum where the function is telling there is some).

```
v <- df$a
findpeaks <- function(v, 
                      bw = 10, 
                      x.coo = c(1:length(v)))
{
  pos.x.max <- NULL
  pos.y.max <- NULL
  pos.x.min <- NULL
  pos.y.min <- NULL     
  for(i in 1:(length(v)-1))     {       if((i+1+bw)>length(v)){
    sup.stop <- length(v)}else{sup.stop <- i+1+bw
    }
    if((i-bw)<1){inf.stop <- 1}else{inf.stop <- i-bw}
    subset.sup <- v[(i+1):sup.stop]
    subset.inf <- v[inf.stop:(i-1)]
    
    is.max   <- sum(subset.inf > v[i]) == 0
    is.nomin <- sum(subset.sup > v[i]) == 0
    
    no.max   <- sum(subset.inf > v[i]) == length(subset.inf)
    no.nomin <- sum(subset.sup > v[i]) == length(subset.sup)
    
    if(is.max & is.nomin){
      pos.x.max <- c(pos.x.max, x.coo[i])
      pos.y.max <- c(pos.y.max, v[i])
    }
    if(no.max & no.nomin){
      pos.x.min <- c(pos.x.min,x.coo[i])
      pos.y.min <- c(pos.y.min,v[i])
    }
  }
  return(list(pos.x.max,pos.y.max,pos.x.min,pos.y.min))
}
findpeaks(v)
sapply(df, function(x) findpeaks(x))
```

which gave
[image: output data findpeaks]

columns x and z are correct but other columns should be located elsewhere (i.e. LocationOfPeak_var."a", "b", "c" or "d").

If I'm not clear, I can give more details on my question.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to SO. Could you please have a look at your formatting? It looks all over the place and it makes it harder to understand what's data and what's question. Moreover, why doesn't your solution _really satisfy you_? What is missing?

Comment: Hello, i add some details to my question, Much thanks.